# How to get the confidence interval, error tradeoff and the frequency distribution plots for the glmtree predictions

Tags: r

I am using the `glmtree` function, from the `partykit` package:

```
fit <- glmtree(formula= fD ~ 1 | Age + fGender + Qualification + fOccupation + SizeWorkplc + WorkExp, data=newdata, family="binomial", minsize = 50, maxdepth = 4, alpha = 0.9, prune = "AIC")
```

To predict the model I am using:

```
prob <-predict(fit,newdata=newdata,type=c("response"))
```

I'd like to have the confidence interval of the prediction.
I have tried `se.fit=TRUE`, `confint` function, `interval="prediction"`, ....

I'd to know how to get the error tradeoff plot and the frequency distribution of probability plot predicted by the model presence and absence sites (once family ="binomial").